# Laravel output response and exit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel's `send()` method appears to be only echo'ing the content and nothing else. I'm calling an inner function from my controller, which under certain circumstances (ajax request) needs to send a json response and then terminate the application:

`response()->json($data)->send();`

I might use a simple `exit;` call afterwards, but that wouldn't be a graceful shutdown.

My previous framework response output function was flushing the buffers, echo'ing the response and calling exit at the end.

What is the proper way to output a response and exit in Laravel 5.5?

---

Brief snippet so you can see what I'm about. **Keep in mind that this is shortened A LOT, just for you to get my point**:

Controller method:

```
public function create( Request $request )
{
    $uploads = new Helpers\Upload();

    return view( 'page.create' )->withUpload($upload)->withForm( $this->form );
}
```

Upload class:

```
class Upload
{
     public function __construct()
     {
           if (request()->ajax() && request()->server('key'))
           {
               $data = [];
               // AJAX. Do some job, output json and exit
               [..]
               response()->json($data)->send();
               exit; // current way of terminating, not graceful though
           }

           // No ajax, do the usual stuff, setup class and return string
           [..]
           return 'My string';
     }
}
```

Comment: you can use  return response()->json($data)->send();

Comment: I think it's `return response()->json($data);`

Comment: See my edit guys...

Comment: The *real* question is - why would you have to terminate the app and not let it do its cleanup procedure? What's so mandatory that you must terminate it yourself, and if you HAVE to terminate it, what's wrong with `exit;`? It exists for such purpose. What are you even doing? The proper way is to `return response()->json()` and not fiddle with terminating stuff yourself.

Comment: @Mjh As you are able to see in delivered code, I'm terminating it in case I need to return json for AJAX. It IS mandatory, not to return the whole view along with my JSON as you can see in delivered code. `exit;` is wrong for the reason you specified in the first sentence. I know two frameworks that allowing me to gracefully terminate, hence the question.

Comment: Well you're using the framework wrong, and your assumptions are wrong. When you need to return JSON, you can inspect whether your response wants JSON back. It's `$request->wantsJson();`. You can easily check if the request is done via XmlHttpRequest or not that way and return json response, otherwise a view. There's no need to do anything such as invoking a send method or terminating the framework yourself.

Comment: @Mjh Of course, I can do that. But that will require me to make checks in every controller method where the class is used. Thats what I don't want to happend and thats why I want to send & terminate.

Comment: Oh, and it's completely fine to use framework that way. Laravel's validate() method sends errors as json, if request expect json. However - you don't need to return validate() method to send it's content. It will terminate script execution and send json. This is similar behaviour to mine.

Comment: I'm not sure you have much choice about this - if you want to exit from a class you have called from a controller, then you need to send that up to the controller and exit there. You could use a custom exception to skip to the controller method, and catch that to do a clean exit.

Answer (score -1):

Use `return` to terminate the function and return some data:

```
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: As I said, it's a inner function. Returning will have no effect.

Comment: There you go, hope it helps

Comment: @Kesse Maybe i'm not seeing it all,  but right now i'm quite sure my answer fits your question. Give it a try.

Comment: It's not. Dont you understand I need to terminate the application after that response within ajax call check but NOT return so it wouldn't return my view as well?

Comment: It is. This is *exactly* what you're after, based on your description. There are two possibilities - you're unable to explain what you're after or you're impervious to understanding that this *is* what you asked for. Proper way to solve this is to explain what exactly you need to do, without posting a code snippet that doesn't help anyone. This is an XY problem.

Comment: @MjH Maybe you need to see the question again. It's pretty clear: `What is the proper way to output a response and exit in Laravel 5.5?`. If there is no way, throw it up. No need to teach me about X and Y

Comment: @Kesse - I'm not the one asking question. You are. You're also cocky with little to show. The question isn't about terminating the framework's process, the problem was in you not understanding what to do depending on result that needs to be returned (json or a view). Yes, it is XY problem. You're asking about your *perceived* solution. Not about the **real** problem. What you're looking for is *thank you*.

Comment: @Mjh Can't agree. The question is simple and clear. It's doesn't matter when I terminate (depending on result). Stop looking deeper in my code please, because you're missing the point. All that matters if how to gracefully output and terminate. You need to understand that. If there is no way - post such question and we're done.

Comment: @Mjh I didn't mean to offend you but why are you trying to be smart here. You keep saying that I should keep returning my response, which in fact will continue and render the view along with the json. Thats not the idea. `send` function is there for a reason. Don't tell me it's bad to send different content type, depending on the request type. If Laravel would allow me to gracefully terminate it's process, like other frameworks do, that would fix my actual problem.

Comment: Yes, you should `return` your response. That terminates the rest of the function. I wrote that you're using the framework wrong, but you didn't want to read/understand why.  I'm not offended, it's not me who's asking the question. Is there a better way to do what you're doing? Yes, there is. Do you have to "terminate" the framework on your own? No, you don't. Can you assert what type of request was made and return appropriate response? Yes, you can. But, you're doing it manually and you apparently want validation for your approach - well, I'm sorry, it's not good. As I said - all the best, GL!